# How to declare ES6 iterable callback (delegate) in typescript

Tags: typescript, iterator

I'm declaring my delegates/callbacks as:

```
export interface SomeDelegate {
    (): void;
}
```

however I have no clue how to declare iterable callback

```
export interface SomeDelegate {
    function *(): Iterable<any>;
}
```

Any ideas?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it seems that you can declare ordinary delegate that returns Iterator and have it assigned with generator function...